# PassportJS Auth with JWT and Goolge

Tags: javascript, express, passport.js, passport-google-oauth, passport-jwt

So when I try to auth a user in the api with jwt or google the passport.authenticate redirects to google

```
passport.authenticate(["jwt", "google"], { session: false, scope: ["profile", "email"] })
```

[image]

I can't figure out how to change it when I try doing a custom middleware it always bugs out with passport.authenticate(), How can I make this work

EDIT:
This middleware seemed to work fine,

```
  function checkAuthenticated(req, res, next)  {
        if (req.isAuthenticated()) { return next() }
        passport.authenticate("jwt", { session: false })(req, res, next);
   }
```

Hoping for a better solution or fix.